# Inheritance : transform a base class instance to a child class instance

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have an instance of a base class, and then I want to make it an instance of a child class of this base class. Maybe I'm taking the problem in a wrong way and there's something important I didn't understand in OOP. Code is only there to illustrate and a very different approach can be suggested. Any help appreciated.

```
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

    def drive(self):
        print "Driving at 50 mph"

class FastCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, color, max_speed=100):
        Car.__init__(self, color)
        self.max_speed = max_speed

    def drive_fast(self):
        print "Driving at %s mph" %self.max_speed

one_car = Car('blue')

# After the instanciation, I discovered that one_car is not just a classic car
# but also a fast one which can drive at 120 mph.
# So I want to make one_car a FastCar instance.
```

I see a very similar question, but none of the answers suits my problem :

- I don't want to make FastCar a wrapper around Car which would know how to drive fast : I really want that FastCar extends Car ;
- I don't really want to use the `__new__` method in FastCar to make some tests on the arguments and decide if `__new__` has to return a new instance of Car or the instance I gave to it (example:     `def __new__(cls, color, max_speed=100, baseclassinstance=None)`).

Comment: Why don't u just do: one_car = FastCar(one_car.color, 120) ? It's not really inheritance or anything but should work.

Comment: Your OOP design seems a little off. I would imagine that FastCar would also implement drive(), but would do so at the higher speed (what you have implemented as drive_fast). With what you have now, the caller has to know the type to know which method to call (bad), instead of calling the same method and having the various types implement that method as appropriate (good).  You could also do this by just adding `drive = drive_fast` at the end of the FastCar class.

Comment: Ok. A better example : `FastCar` doesn't have a `drive_fast` method but a `overtake` method, which doesn't exist for a `Car`.

Comment: @Eugene @agf @Peter Ok, my example was far too simplistic. The whole thing is that I don't want to create a new object, and I don't want to have two different instances. If it helps, let's say that `Car` comes from an external module and that `color` is in fact `__color`, a private member of `Car`. Or that `Car.__init__` does not only assign `color` to `self.color`  but makes heavy computations whith color (which is in fact a big `numpy.array`) and that I can't repeat these computations to create a `FastCar`.

Comment: Since there are no real private members in Python, you can just use a version of either one of my methods -- just copy the computed attribute over to the new instance (method 1) or change only the class and whatever methods are necessary when you're fiddling with it's attributes (my method2) -- this all assuming you still don't want to have conditional `__new__` or `__init__`s. Probably though, if you think you need to do this, you need to re-design your inheritance / class structure.

Comment: @Andy - your "better example" is even worse. You design is the same, you just renamed the offending method. Much of the time that I use inheritance is to get polymorphism, which requires consistent call interface from the subclass to the superclass.  Google for "Liskov Substitution Principle".

Answer (score 3):

```
class FastCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, color, max_speed=100):
        Car.__init__(self, color)
        self.max_speed = max_speed

    def drive_fast(self):
        print "Driving at %s mph" %self.max_speed

    @staticmethod
    def fromOtherCar(car):
        return FastCar(car.color)

actually_fast = FastCar.fromOtherCar(thought_was_classic)
```

This is the standard way.

Depending on the real class layout, you may be able to do something like:

```
classic = Car('blue')

classic.__class__ = FastCar
classic.__dict__.update(FastCar(classic.color).__dict__)

classic.drive_fast()
```

But I wouldn't recommend it -- it's a hack, it won't always work, and the other way is cleaner.

**Edit:** Was just about to add basically what @PaulMcGuire's comment says. Follow that advice, he's right.

Answer (score 0):

You can borrow the C++ notion of a "copy constructor" to do something like this.

Allow Car's constructor to take a Car instance, and copy all of its properties.  FastCar should then accept either Car instances or FastCar instances.

So then, to convert the car, you would just do `one_car = FastCar(one_car)`.  Note that this will not affect references to the original Car object, which will remain pointing to the same Car.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use one class?

```
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, color, max_speed = 50):
        self.color = color
        self.max_speed = max_speed
    def drive(self):
        print "Driving at %s mph"%self.max_speed

c=Car('blue')
c.max_speed = 100
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not common in OOP to change type (class) of a living object after instantiation. I know barely two languages that would allow that as a *dirty hack*. The whole purpose of types (classes) is to know beforehand what operations an object can and can not perform. If you want something like this, you're probably mistaking the idea of OOP.

Comment: If you were new to OOP I think you might think of making a string from a character array changing the type of an object. It's making a new object from the contents of the old one, which is what he really wants to do (he just doesn't know it).

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think this what I want to do. I really don't want to create a new object.